# Unable to see icon of my app

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image, android-icons

I cannot see the icon of app created.When i go to to application manager in my device it shows the app installed.But i cannot see any icon for the app in my device.
The manifest file clearly states:  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" but i cant see any icon.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myfirstapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you need to have a intent filter or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not a activity

```
        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

in the androidManifest.xml,

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

it means when click the application icon, it launcher the activity.

the launcher didn't know the mainactivity, so it does not show the app icon.